# Unity3D: How to convert a mesh's color's array to a texture2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, mesh, texture-mapping

I'm generating a mesh using Perlin Noise and Shader Graph to add colors based on height.

I want to have a texture of the mesh so it will be used as a minimap.

How do I convert the `mesh.colors` to a `Texture2D` variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: fe. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html

Comment: Unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve ... a mesh is in 3D space .. a texture 2D in 2D space ... so you would somehow need to UV map the mesh to a Texture2D ...

Answer (score 0):

If your mesh is a plane mesh with `textureWidth`*`textureHeight`  vertices you can do:

```
public Mesh mesh;
public int textureWidth;
public int textureHeight;
public Texture2D GenerateTexture2D(){
    Texture2D texture2D = new Texture2D(textureWidth, textureHeight);

    for(int h=0; h<textureHeight; h++)
        for(int w=0; w<textureWidth; w++)
            texture2D.SetPixel(w, h, mesh.colors[h*textureWidth + w]);

    return texture2D;
}
```

> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html

or: (Thanks to @yes)

```
public Mesh mesh;
public int textureWidth;
public int textureHeight;
public Texture2D GenerateTexture2D(){
    Texture2D texture2D = new Texture2D(textureWidth, textureHeight);
    texture2D.SetPixels(mesh.colors);
    return texture2D;
}
```

> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html

Comment: since he wants to use vertex colors (mesh.colors) and its already an one dimensional array of color why not just use `SetPixels(Color[])`?

Comment: @yes Thanks, didn't know about it.